# JPA, Spring-Boot and PostgresQL. Webapp tries to generate already existing primary keys after importing a population script

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm developing a webapp using Spring-Boot 2 and PostGresQL. My problem is that development started using MYSQL 8.0 and H2 as databases and I didn't had any issue with those. Due to deploy constraints I have to configure a PostGresQL database.

I found that after importing my population script my webapp would try to generate repeated IDs, already existing ones from the script, instead of following after the last ID contained in the database.

This is my BaseEntity.class

```
/**
    * Simple JavaBean domain object with an id property. Used as a base class for objects
    * needing this property.
    *
    * @author Ken Krebs
    * @author Juergen Hoeller
    */

@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Integer id;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isNew() {
    return this.id == null;
}

}
```

And a portion of the population sql script

```
-- Valoraciones Usuario 1
INSERT INTO valoracion(id, puntuacion, comentario, beaver_id, author_id) VALUES (1, 4.5, 'Muy profesional, su trabajo ha sido perfecto y muy puntual.', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO valoracion(id, puntuacion, comentario, beaver_id, author_id) VALUES (2, 3.5, 'Profesional y puntual.', 1, 3);
INSERT INTO valoracion(id, puntuacion, comentario, beaver_id, author_id) VALUES (3, 2.1, 'Mucho arte, pero nada puntual con la entrega.', 1, 4);
INSERT INTO valoracion(id, puntuacion, comentario, beaver_id, author_id) VALUES (4, 1.0, 'Pésimo trabajo. Nada profesional.', 1, 5);
INSERT INTO valoracion(id, puntuacion, comentario, beaver_id, author_id) VALUES (5, 3.3, 'Puntual y barato.', 1, 6);
INSERT INTO valoracion(id, puntuacion, comentario, beaver_id, author_id) VALUES (6, 5.0, 'Su trabajo es increible, lo recomiendo.', 1, 7);
INSERT INTO valoracion(id, puntuacion, comentario, beaver_id, author_id) VALUES (7, 1.2, 'Malisimo trabajo, nada satisfecho.', 1, 8);
```

Comment: Use a sequence, both for the population script and refer your entity to it

Comment: Even no need to refer a sequence in entity, GenerationType.IDENTITY will handle it if primary key type is SERIAL.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to restart the id sequence on your table.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq RESTART WITH 8;
```